# Django 2. Как скачать архивом папку

Tags: python-3.x, django

Есть необходимость реализовать в приложении возможность скачать в виде архива содержимое конкретной папки.

Нашёл несколько примеров. В итоге, архив скачивается, но не открывается через WinRAR, при этом размер архива 0 байт. Получается, что данные в архив не записываюся. При различных попытках разобраться, натыкался на ошибку `"Attempt to use ZIP archive that was already closed"`, но в примерах, логика отправки архива, реализуется после закрытия самого архива.

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема. Спасибо!

```py
class DownloadZip(View):
    absolute_path = 'E:\\TestDir'
    archive_name = os.path.basename(os.path.basename(absolute_path))
    file_type = '.zip'
    file_name = archive_name + file_type

    def get(self, request):
        temp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
        new_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(temp, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

        for root, folder, files in os.walk(self.absolute_path):
            new_zip.write(root)
            for file in files:
                new_zip.write(os.path.join(root, file))
        new_zip.close()

        wrapper = FileWrapper(temp) #?
        response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(new_zip), content_type='application/zip')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={0}'.format(urlquote(self.file_name))
        temp.seek(0)
        return response
```

Answer (score 1):

Подсмотрел решение.

```py
class DownloadZip(View):
    absolute_path = 'E:\\TestDir'
    archive_name = os.path.basename(os.path.basename(absolute_path))
    file_type = '.zip'
    file_name = archive_name + file_type

    def get(self, request):
        file_path = list()

        for root, folder, files in os.walk(self.absolute_path):
            file_path.append(root)
            for file in files:
                file_path.append(os.path.join(root, file))

        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/zip')
        new_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(response, 'w')

        with zipfile.ZipFile(response, 'w') as zip:
            for file in file_path:
                zip.write(file)
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={0}'.format(urlquote(self.file_name))
            return response
```